# Git tagging - best practice

Tags: git, tags

The Git tag is confusing me a bit. I'm not sure if this is the right place to post it.

I have two branches. Develop and master. If I want to tag it with release info, should I tag the develop or master branch? The tag needs to be on both (pipeline suffixes develop as unstable).

I initially tagged develop with 0.1.0 and then master with 1.0.0 when the first release was finished, but this created some odd behaviour with the 'is really' issue whenever I switched branches. Should I have had both tags on the develop branch? Will the tag automatically be merged with master when I merge the branches or does that need to be done manually?

Comment: I suggest you post a sketch/diagram of your tree. This may be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

ASAIK, it's better to tag on the 'master' branch with a particular **commit**. Usually, git tag refer to a commit.

As we push the changes from 'master' branch to the production - I'll use the last commit as a reference to the git tagging.

Answer (score 0):

I will advice to tag the master branch but commits on both branches can be tagged. After the merge, the tagged commit will be an ancestor of both branches.